# Determine total number of perimeter dots based on rectangle's length & width dots [C#]

Tags: c#

awesome community. I'm new to this platform nonetheless I'll try being detailed, yet brief with my request.

[image]

The above image shows a rectangle of length 5 units (as dots) & 4 dots width. Now, is there a way to get the total number of dots used to cover the perimeter of the rectangle in C#? One can visually understand there are a total of 14 dots, but I want the program to determine them 14 dots by discerning the 5 dots length & 4 dots width.

Using C# winform, I've placed a textbox for length & another for width. Another textbox as result to denote the total number of dots. No graphical work or anything fancy. Just calculation.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is nothing to do with C#, it's just plain maths.

Comment: `2*H+2*(W-2)`. You have to subtract both corners from the top and bottom sides or you would count them twice, since they're already part of the left and right sides, hence why there is a -2 in there. So `2*5+2*(4-2)` --> `10+2*2` --> `14`, as you said.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a maths question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 7):

That is super easy math question.

Simply that is  2 * (first side length) + 2 * (second side length) - 4 (the four corners).

In your case 2 * 5 + 2 * 4 - 4 = 14

Answer (score 0):

let's use W for width and H for height, so:

the total area is:

```
W x H = 20
```

the inner area is:

```
(W - 2) x (H - 2) = 6
```

so just deduct inner from total area:

```
(W x H) - ((W - 2) x (H - 2)) = 14
```